# Updating Angular 5 to Angular 6 getting an error on Package "ng2-pdf-viewer" has a missing peer dependency

Tags: npm, angular5, angular6

I am trying to update angular from version 5 to version 6.

I executed

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@next
```

And after that i executed the update command. Getting the below error for ng2-pdf-viewer.

```
ng update --all
              Package "ng2-pdf-viewer" has a missing peer dependency of 
             "pdfjs-dist" @ "2.0.489".Invalid range: ">=5.0.0"
```

By seeing the error it asking pdfjs-dist to install, but is there any way to use without adding that.

Appreciate your help here.

Comment: you can manually use ng update "package-specific name", instead of --all. That will not show you to install pdfjs-dist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the package manually as followed

```
npm install ng2-pdf-viewer@latest
```

then run ng update again